# How to test mobile devices with Google PageSpeed Insights API

Tags: google-pagespeed-insights-api

I tried API based on the document https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started?hl=en

It gives `"emulatedFormFactor": "desktop"`

Is there anyway to change it to `mobile`?

I'm expecting something like below in web-app

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=JA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com&tab=mobile

There, we can change device by querying `tab=mobile` or `tab=desktop`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `strategy` and this accepts either "desktop" or "mobile".

So in the example you gave it would be:-

[`https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&strategy=mobile`](https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&strategy=mobile)

It appears you also wanted it to be in Japanese if I understand correctly?

To use different languages / local formatting you would append `locale`.

So add `&locale=ja` for Japanese I believe. This is the equivalent of `hl=JA` in the URL you posted.